# ADO.NET Entity Framework generates unexpected, problem INSERTs

Tags: .net, wpf, linq, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I need some help understanding the ADO.NET Entity Framework.

I'm trying to represent and manipulate hierarchical data in a WPF TreeView control with the ADO.NET Entity Framework.

[ADO.NET Entity Framework Object with parent and children http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/7158/thingpi1.gif](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/7158/thingpi1.gif)

Each of these Things has a single parent and zero or more children.

My "delete" button...

```
Private Sub ButtonDeleteThing_Click(...)
    db.DeleteObject(DirectCast(TreeViewThings.SelectedItem, Thing))
    db.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

I'm monitoring the SQL Server Profiler while I debug my application:

1. The first button click deletes just fine.
2. The second button click inserts a duplicate parent (but with empty GUID uniqueidentifier primary key) and then performs the delete.
3. The third button click fails (Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint) because it cannot insert another row with an empty GUID primary key.

The unexpected, generated T-SQL duplication...

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Thing]([Id], [ParentId], ...)
values (@0, @1, ...) ',N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 uniqueidentifier,...',
@0='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
@1='389D987D-79B1-4A9D-970F-CE15F5E3E18A',
...
```

But, it's not just deletes.  My "add" button has similar behavior with unexpected inserts.  It follows the same pattern.

This makes me think there's a more fundamental problem with how I'm binding these entity classes to the WPF TreeView or with my data model itself.

Here's the relevant code...

XAML...

```
<TreeView Name="TreeViewThings"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewThings_Expanded"
          TreeViewItem.Selected="TreeViewThings_Selected"
          ... >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Thing}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
<Button Name="ButtonAddThing" Content="Add Thing" ... />
<Button Name="ButtonDeleteThing" Content="Delete Thing" ... />
```

Visual Basic...

```
Partial Public Class Window1

    Dim db As New ThingProjectEntities

    Private Sub Window1_Loaded(...) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        TreeViewThings.ItemsSource = _
            From t In db.Thing.Include("Children") _
            Where (t.Parent Is Nothing) _
            Select t
    End Sub

    Private Sub TreeViewThings_Expanded(...)
        Dim ExpandedTreeViewItem As TreeViewItem = _
            DirectCast(e.OriginalSource, TreeViewItem)
        LoadTreeViewChildren(ExpandedTreeViewItem)
    End Sub

    Sub LoadTreeViewChildren(ByRef Parent As TreeViewItem)
        Dim ParentId As Guid = DirectCast(Parent.DataContext, Thing).Id
        Dim ChildThings As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Thing)
        ChildThings = From t In db.Thing.Include("Children") _
                      Where t.Parent.Id = ParentId _
                      Select t
        Parent.ItemsSource = ChildThings
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonAddThing_Click(...)
        Dim NewThing As New Thing
        NewThing.Id = Guid.NewGuid()
        Dim ParentId As Guid = _
            DirectCast(TreeViewThings.SelectedItem, Thing).Id
        NewThing.Parent = (From t In db.Thing _
                           Where t.Id = ParentId _
                           Select t).First
        ...
        db.AddToThing(NewThing)
        db.SaveChanges()
        TreeViewThings.UpdateLayout()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonDeleteThing_Click(...)
        db.DeleteObject(DirectCast(TreeViewThings.SelectedItem, Thing))
        db.SaveChanges()
    End Sub

    ...

End Class
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why is it generating these strange inserts?

---

Update:

I've made a breakthrough.  But, I still can't explain it.

I'd gotten rid of the cause when I simplified my code for this question.

Rather than using Linq such as:

```
From t In db.Thing.Include("Children") Where ...
```

I've been using Linq such as:

```
From t In db.Thing.Include("Children").Include("Brand") Where ...
```

You see, My Thing entity is related to another Brand entity.

[ADO.NET Entity Framework Object with parent and children and a related Object http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/3268/thingbrandct4.gif](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/3268/thingbrandct4.gif)

I thought it was irrelevant, so I didn't include it in the question above.

Apparently this was the cause of my unexpected, problem inserts in my Thing table.

But, why?  Can anyone explain why this was happening?  I'd like to understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you loading the parent again when adding a new child, when you already have the object? While this is no problem for the database, it will introduce inconsistencies on the object level. You can just use the existing parent like this:

```
Private Sub ButtonAddThing_Click(...)
    Dim NewThing As New Thing
    NewThing.Id = Guid.NewGuid()
    Dim Parent As Thing = DirectCast(TreeViewThings.SelectedItem, Thing)
    NewThing.Parent = Parent
    ...
    db.AddToThing(NewThing)
    db.SaveChanges()
    TreeViewThings.UpdateLayout()
End Sub
```

About the delete: have you specified cascading deletes in the database?

Comment: The Entity Framework preserves entity identity. While it is perhaps inefficient to load the parent from the database every time, it will not "introduce inconsistencies." You can load the same entity as many times as you like and it will still be treated as the same entity.

Comment: I'm not trying to do any cascading.  I'm only deleting a single row from the database.  There should be no INSERTs.

Comment: At one time I had NewThing.Parent = DirectCast(TreeViewThings.SelectedItem, Thing), but changed it while trying to troubleshoot.  It can probably be changed back.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a detailed look at the code but the first thing to consider is that you shouldn't need to call DeleteObject at every level of your hierarchy. EF like other O/RMs tracks objects and their associations for you.

Let's say, for example, that you have a parent->child 1..* relationship. If you query the parent, remove a child object from the parents Children collection and then call SaveChanges(), EF will generate the appropriate DELETE SQL statements for you - You do not need to track this yourself.

So, a better way to achieve your scenario would be to do this:

1. Query the object hierarchy out of EF.
2. Bind that to your UI. Let your UI modify the in-memory objects as you see fit.
3. When you are done, call SaveChanges and let the EF figure out what to do.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I'm only deleting one Thing at a time.

Comment: It's that "let the EF figure out what to do" part that gives me trouble.

Comment: To delete a child object, it is sufficient to remove it from the object graph. Similarly, to add a new object, add it to the object graph. EF is tracking the graph so will know what to do when you call SaveChanges. Perhaps try writing a unit test outside of your UI to get a feel for how this works.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here. I don't completely understand the relationship between them, but I think I can get you on your way.

The first thing that you need to understand is that the Entity Framework does not deal well with deleting a less-than-fully-materialized instance. That is why Include changes the behavior that you see. So if you have an entity that aggregates a list of children, you need to load those children before calling delete. Only if the child instances are in memory will they be deleted before the parent. So, with or without Include, you need to do something like this before calling Delete.

```
if (!thing.BrandReference.IsLoaded) thing.BrandReference.Load();
```

If you've called Include on the relationship, then this will do nothing if you haven't, then it will ensure that everything is materialized before you

The second thing that unique understand is that [inserting a new entity with a relationship to an existing entity is conceptually two different inserts](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/02/20/side-effects-of-first-class-associations.aspx). This is a consequence of the fact that relationships are first-class in the Entity Framework. The first insert is the entity itself, the second is the relationship. In this case, there is no separate table for the relationship, so only one actual insert to the database as needed. However, the Entity Framework can only figure this out if it is mapped correctly.

So what is going on in this case? What follows is my speculation based on some of the things I see going on here. But I think the situation is even more complicated than I'm describing, so I believe what follows is incorrect in some of the details. It may be close enough to help you solve the actual problem, though.

1. You had an instance that was less-than-fully-materialized before you tried to delete it.
2. When you tried to delete something else, the framework tried to look into the same relationship. It found things out of whack and tried, unsuccessfully, to put things back into a good state.
3. Then you tried to delete again, 2 repeats, only this time it is even less successful, due to the database constraint.
4. Using Include fixes the issue in 1.

Comment: This one failed:  From t In db.Thing.Include("Children").Include("Brand") Where ... without that second Include() it works as expected.  It seems that rather than being "less-than-fully-materialized" they were "over-materialized".  But why would that be possible.